# CROSS JOIN with table that has no row

Tags: postgresql, join

In definition;

```
SELECT * 
from T1, T2
```

Cross Join: If T1 has N rows, T2 has M rows, the result set will have N x M rows.

If T2 has no row, then result of the JOIN has no row also.

However, I want N rows (from T1), what can I do?

Any suggestion?

Note: I want cartesian product, there is no shared column between the tables.

Comment: sounds as if you want a full outer join instead

Comment: No I want cartesian product. There is no shared column between two table.

Comment: I know :) I asked how I solve my problem.

Comment: So you want the non-empty table if either one of the tables is empty, but a cross join if both have rows?

Comment: Maybe but not a good solution.

Comment: Could you explain your purpose?  I see no reason or advantage to do that.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use `CROSS JOIN` if any of both sets has no rows for the output you want. You can simulate this behaviour with a `FULL JOIN` with an *always true* condition.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    T1
    FULL JOIN T2 ON true
```

Comment: @JohnPuskin: so you do want a full outer join ;)